# What is Etherparty?

Tags: contract-development

[Etherparty](http://etherparty.io/) is a platform that removes the complexity and management of creating and executing smart contracts.

What exactly does that mean, and how does that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Etherparty was inspired by Counterparty, a metaprotocol on Bitcoin that made it easier to issue tokens, and had/has some other features such as a distributed exchange.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SadoYzu0fT0

AFAIK Etherparty wanted to bring exactly those features to Ethereum.  From what I can see now however, the project is dead.  The blog and Twitter account have been silent for months:

- http://blog.etherparty.io/
- https://twitter.com/etherparty_io

The reason probably is that it's so easy to develop on Ethereum there's no need for an extra layer dumbing it down.

Comment: There are countless reasons why we need a safe, secure and non-developer platform for smart contracts as the blockchain ecosystem develops and applications become more mainstream. Think of the supply chain manager (NOT a developer) who needs to author a smart contract for permission-less provenance of suppliers, and many other use cases.

Answer (score 4):

As one of the founders of Etherparty I can assure you we are not dead.

Over the winter I was dedicating time to help the Ethereum foundation which unfortunately put things with Etherparty on hold.

The project is currently in development and we believe fundamentally that developing on Ethereum should be accessible to everyone.

The platform will leverage visual programming tools to enable the non technical to customize and execute their own smart contracts.

As per our latest Facebook post, we are in the midst of hiring developers to finish out the remaining beta.

Answer (score 3):

We just closed our seed round to finish development, with that we hired a senior developer, web developer, and solidity developer - still looking for more blockchain devs if anyone is in Vancouver!

Product Roadmap and Architecture document is on its way.

Answer (score 0):

This beta is still not out.
It is hard to find information about why this project fell through.

But after researching recent activity it seems basically dead.
Maybe Lisa Cheng can clarify why development has stalled.

Comment: This is not an answer to anything.  Please use comments when requiring further information.

Comment: You're welcome to check out the updated information on the beta on etherparty.io. We also just demo'd this product in London in July.